# LineChart with optional Y parameter swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts, swiftcharts

Require a LineChart where in it allows `y` value as `nil`. As when no data for that particular day(`x`) is there the line should just go forward.

Currently I have researched on [SwiftChart](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts) & [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) but both doesn't provide that functionality.

Please refer below image for more understanding.

[image]

As you can see Sunday, Monday & Wednesday there is data Tuesday there is no data so the line just continues from Monday to Wednesday.

How can I achieve this or if there is any library that can help me achieve this.

Comment: "the line should just go forward", isn't this what it is doing in the image?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts, if I skip some X value it will be shown like that, it depends on your data value

Comment: @aiwiguna I think if you skip x i.e. in my case Tuesday then it won't be shown on the x axis. If I misunderstood what you told then can you please shown in code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yeah the image is what I have got from the designer, in actual result Y value touches zero of Tuesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just skip some X value in https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

[image]

```
private func setupChart() {
        let leftAxis = chart.leftAxis
        leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        leftAxis.axisMaximum = 100
        leftAxis.granularity = 10
        
        let rightAxis = chart.rightAxis
        rightAxis.enabled = false
        
        let xAxis = chart.xAxis
        xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
        xAxis.axisMaximum = 7
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.granularity = 1
        
    }
    
    private func setupChartData() {
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0...7 {
            if i % 2 == 0 {
                let value = arc4random_uniform(100) + 1
                if value != 0 {
                    let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(value))
                    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
                }
            }
        }
        let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "")
        let data = LineChartData(dataSet: dataSet)
        chart.data = data
    }
```